# Symmetric 2D array of random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```java
public static int[][] Matrix(int n, int max, int min) {
    int[][] grid = new int[3][3];
    Random rand = new Random();

    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int value = Math.abs((min + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1)));
            grid[i][j] = value;
            grid[j][i] = value;
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

The following code prints a 2D symmetric array where the values are random numbers between a range (min and max) which prints the following result as example:

```
0 14 11 
14 0 17 
11 17 0
```

My problem with the code is it only prints `0` as the diagonal value. How can I change it to print the diagonal values where they are set as int min instead of `0`? For example, in the code above int min is `8` hence it would give this result:

```
8 14 11 
14 8 17 
11 17 8
```

Comment: is PrintArray a built in java method or is it a method of your creation? Java could recognize it.

Comment: @ColeHenrich i created a separate method which i have not added in this code

Comment: please add it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the diagonal to the lower variable, you need to do two things.

One, because you set j < i, j will never equal i, meaning the diagonal will be set to 0 because Java initializes integers to 0 if they aren't given an explicit initialization value. I was able to access the diagonal by simply changing the < to an <=:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Two, once i equals j, you need to add an if statement that checks for the case where they're equal. When they are, simply set the current grid cell to the lower variable. Don't forget to enclose the other half of the second for code block with an else block or you'll get unintended behavior:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
{
    if(i == j)
    {
        grid[i][j] = lower;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, your whole for loop block should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    for( int j = 0; j <= i; j++) 
    {
        if(i == j)
        {
            grid[i][j] = lower;
        }
        else
        {
            int value = Math.abs((lower + rand.nextInt((upper - lower) + 1)));   
            grid[i][j] = value;
            grid[j][i] = value;
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I also have another question related to the same question. I want this code to be able to return null when n<=0 but when i use if (n<= 0) {return null;}, it displays an error. how can i fix this?

Comment: When you say you want to return null, do you mean you just want the code to print null if n is too small?

Comment: yes if n<=0 , print  null. i tried adding the if statement but it returns an error

Answer (score 0):

You are generating random value for all `i` and `j` except when `i==j`, which are the diagonal values. Also, all the values of the diagonals will be same. So before returning the grid, you can generate one last random value and put it to the diagonals. Something like this

```
int diagonalValue = Math.abs((min+ rand.nextInt((max- min) + 1)));   
for( int k=0 ; k<n ; k++) 
{
    grid[k][k] = diagonalValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code review:

- Add invalid syntax checks to the beginning of the method;
- `Math.abs` is redundant;
- The inner loop should include the upper bound;

Your code might look something like this:

```java
public static int[][] matrix(int n, int max, int min) {
    // incorrect matrix size
    if (n <= 0)
        return new int[][]{{}};
    int[][] grid = new int[n][n];
    // incorrect random value bound
    if (max - min <= 0)
        return grid;

    Random rand = new Random();
    // interval excluding upper bound
    IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i ->
            // interval including upper bound
            IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i).forEach(j -> {
                if (i == j) {
                    // main diagonal
                    grid[i][j] = min;
                } else {
                    // peripheral elements
                    int value = min + rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1);
                    grid[i][j] = value;
                    grid[j][i] = value;
                }
            }));
    return grid;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.stream(matrix(5, 9, 1))
            .map(Arrays::toString)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 3, 3, 2]
[6, 1, 9, 4, 2]
[3, 9, 1, 6, 7]
[3, 4, 6, 1, 9]
[2, 2, 7, 9, 1]
```